# Is there a horizontally-aligning version of the featherlight gallery?

Tags: html, css

I'm using featherlight for my image gallery, as well as lazyload (this makes images load only when they are on the visible part of the page). However, featherlight works by loading images into x-number of vertical columns, meaning every time I scroll, all the images shift as those below load (due to lazyload) and move into position. Is there some way of making the images align in horizontal rows, instead of vertical columns, while still keeping all the other functions of featherlight? If not, is there another similar, simple lightbox gallery that would work in this way? Thank you very much.

Comment: you can do that with a simple `css` also. Simply use `display: inline-block;`